# print if timestamp is greater than a minute

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk

I have lines of input containing 8 fields. Like so:

```
Field1  Field2  Field3  Field4  Field5  Field6  Field7    Field8
name    ID      number  stuff   Jan15   ?       00:00:00  some command
```

One of the fields, Field7, is a timestamp like so `00:00:00`
I would like to "scan" this 7th field and see if the time is greater than one minute, i.e if the 7th field is greater than 00:01:00.

If the 7th field is greater I would then like to print the values of fields 2 7 and 8 to a file. I have very little experience with awk, but from what I understand this is the tool I want to use.

Comment: Please post more clear example/sample of input and expected output and remove `xxx` from your samples, to make it more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***EDIT1:*** To run it with `ps` command use it like:

```
ps -ef | awk '
{
  split($7,array,":")
  tot_time=array[2]*60+array[3]
  if(tot_time>60){
    print $2,$7,$8
  }
  tot_time=""
  delete array
}
'
```

Also to cover 1 edge case of where process running for exact 1 hour and lesser than a min :) try following.

```
ps -ef | awk '
{
  split($7,array,":")
  tot_time=array[1]*3600+array[2]*60+array[3]
  if(tot_time>60){
    print $2,$7,$8
  }
  tot_time=""
  delete array
}
'
```

---

---

Could you please try following. Splitting 7th column into 3 different parts(hours, mins and secs) with having delimiter as `:` and then calculating minutes from it to check either its value is more than 60 or not.

```
awk '
{
  split($7,array,":")
  tot_time=array[2]*60+array[3]
  if(tot_time>60){
    print $2,$7,$8
  }
  tot_time=""
  delete array
}
'   Input_file
```

---

---

***Test with samples:***

```
cat Input_file
Field1  Field2  Field3  Field4  Field5  Field6  Field7  Field8
xxx     xxx     xxx     xxx     xxx     xxx     00:01:01     xxx
xxx     xxx     xxx     xxx     xxx     xxx     00:00:48    xxx
```

After running code following will be the output.

```
awk '
{
  split($7,array,":")
  tot_time=array[2]*60+array[3]
  if(tot_time>60){
    print $2,$7,$8
  }
  tot_time=""
  delete array
}
'  Input_file
xxx 00:01:01 xxx
```

Comment: i piped my input into this awk command and it did seem to work, only nothing printed to the terminal screen and I expected at least a couple of print outs. thank you this helped me understand a bit more what awk can do.

Comment: @JayWehrman, I just added a testing sample with code working and looks it worked fine for me, could you please do lemme know what didn't work exactly here?

Comment: hmm so it works when I make my own input file and give that to awk, but when i try to pipe in echo ps -ef into that same awk script, the file i am writing awks results to is empty.

Comment: @JayWehrman, I have added a EDIT1 solution, could you please check it and lemme know if that helps you?

Comment: thank you so much that worked! I had ```echo``` before ```ps``` in my bash script!

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the fields are separated by whitespaces or tabs, how about:

```
awk '$7 > "00:01:00" {print $2, $7, $8}' file
```

**input**:

```
name1   ID1      number1  stuff   Jan15   ?       00:00:59  somecommand1
name2   ID2      number2  stuff   Jan15   ?       00:01:00  somecommand2
name3   ID3      number3  stuff   Jan15   ?       00:01:01  somecommand3
name4   ID4      number3  stuff   Jan15   ?       00:02:00  somecommand4
```

**output**:

```
ID3 00:01:01 somecommand3
ID4 00:02:00 somecommand4
```

Awk primarily compares two strings as `strings` unless the both are numeric
values or one is a numeric and the other is a numeric string.
In this case `string comparison` is performed then you can directly
compare the time strings in the HH:MM:SS representation.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your file is space/tab separated, this should do the trick:

```
awk '$7!~/^(00:01:00|00:00)/{print $2,$7,$8}' file > out_file
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the following input file:

```
Field1  Field2  Field3  Field4  Field5  Field6  Field7    Field8
name    ID      number  stuff   Jan15   ?       00:00:14  somecommand
name2   ID2     number2 stuff   Jan15   ?       00:00:30  somecommand2
name3   ID3     number3 stuff   Jan15   ?       00:01:30  somecommand3
name4   ID4     number4 stuff   Jan15   ?       01:01:30  somecommand4
name5   ID5     number5 stuff   Jan15   ?       01:00:00  somecommand5
name6   ID6     number6 stuff   Jan15   ?       00:01:00  somecommand5
```

You can use the following `awk` command

```
awk '$7 !~ /(^00:00|00:01:00)/ || NR==1 {print $2,$7,$8}' f.in | column -t
```

It will give the output:

```
Field2  Field7    Field8
ID3     00:01:30  somecommand3
ID4     01:01:30  somecommand4
ID5     01:00:00  somecommand5
```

**Explanations:**

- Approach based on regex
- `NR==1` to print the first line (you can remove this part if not necessary)
- The pattern does not start by `00:00` or is not equal to `00:01:00`, this can be removed if you change your constraint into greater or equal to 1 minute
- print the required fields
- `column -t` is for pretty output, can be removed.